# unable to open MS-Access ADO connection

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to open an Access Database connection using `ADODB.Connection` object through excel VBA but I am receiving an error when opening the connection.

The error is "Object variable or With block variable not set"

I am using excel 2010, my database is in Access 2010 and I have also added the reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 library"

Any help would be highly appreciated

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection

con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\vk10084\Desktop\Jobs\PnL\MyDatabaseFiles\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

**Edit:**

Below is the whole code

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sconString As String
Dim sdbpath As String
Dim sCommand As String

sdbpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database1.accdb"
sCommand = "INSERT INTO Employees VALUES('Vikas Kumar', '263763')"

Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\vk10084\Desktop\Jobs\PnL\POC on Access\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"


cmd.ActiveConnection = con

cmd.CommandText = sCommand
cmd.Execute

con.Close
```

Comment: I would think that error has something to do with another piece of code.  Can you post that whole procedure?

Comment: @Rdster : I just added the whole code

Comment: What happens when you place the sdbpath variable into the connection string?  `con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sdbpath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"`

Comment: As I see it, you missed `New` in `Dim con As New ADODB.Connection`, therefore no Object was created

Comment: Thanks @MartinDreher : `Dim con As New ADODB.Connection` worked just fine.

Comment: damn, was too slow. glad i could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added a `New` to the connection and slightly reordered the code to make it more readable. Does this work?

```
Dim Con As New ADODB.Connection
With Con        
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\vk10084\Desktop\Jobs\PnL\POC on Access\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    .Open
End With

Dim Cmd As New ADODB.Command
With Cmd
    .ActiveConnection = Con
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = sCommand
    .Execute
End With
```